# Are SOS structures better for linear phase FIR filters?

Tags: filters, fixed-point, hardware-implementation, finite-impulse-response

I've seen many discussions suggesting that SOS's are often/usually the preferred structure for fixed point hardware filter implementations, since they preserve conjugate pairs, etc., but I've never seen any specific arguments explaining why they are better for FIR filters.

Do these advantages still apply for direct form, linear phase FIR filters which allow the number of multipliers to be reduced by a factor of 2?

Finally, are there any good resources discussing these trade-offs?  I'm trying to implement fairly long FIR filters with small multipliers, i.e. 40+ taps with 8-10b coefficients, and am looking for resources that might shorten this effort.

Comment: "SOS" usually means cascaded Second Order Sections, no?  i s'pose you can have FIR SOS's, but most of the time "SOS" also means IIR.  IIR's are not precisely linear phase, in the same sense that FIR filters are.  so seeing "SOS" alongside of "linear phase" or "FIR" is confusing to me.

Comment: Right, SOS = second order stage.  My main question is whether SOSs are useful for linear phase FIR filters.  As I mentioned most of the explicit comments about SOS filter's advantages are re: IIR filters.

Answer (score 4):

well, i see little value in factoring an FIR into quadratics and implementing them in cascade.  it won't be computationally cheaper and it's not better from a quantization noise POV if your FIR has access to an accumulator that is double width.

perhaps it will help with limiting coefficient range so that it's less likely that you have non-zero coefficients (at the tails of the FIR) with values of, say, $10^{-8}$ the size of other coefficients (in the middle).  there are other, more efficient ways of dealing with that problem (like computing the FIR from the outside in, doing the tails first and the middle last).

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have any references to the "computing from the outside in" strategy?

Comment: well a paper i remember from a long time ago was from a friend of mine, Duane Wise: [Block Floating-Point FIR Filters Using a Fixed-Point Multiplier](http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=9163).  now if you're using floating-point, the issue is the same.  in FIR summation $$ y[n] = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{L-1} h[i] x[n-i] $$ begin summing the first and last terms first.  then add the second and second to last terms, an so on.  so the $i=\frac{L-1}{2}$ term will be the last one summed.  the impulse response is typically greatest in magnitude in the middle than at the ends.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Robert's answer, but I would like to add why SOS are used for IIR filters, from which it becomes easier to understand why they are not commonly used for implementing FIR filters. One of the reasons why SOS are a very common way of implementing IIR filters is the fact that poles close to each other and/or close to the unit circle make a direct implementation of the transfer function *extremely* sensitive to coefficient quantization. Since FIR filters don't have any poles away from the origin you don't have that problem when implementing FIR filters.

This is not to say that coefficient quantization is no issue for FIR filters. It becomes a problem for large filter lengths and if a high stopband attenuation is desired. In [1] a conservative bound was derived for the error due to coefficient quantization:

$$\epsilon\le 20\log_{10}N-6B\;\text{(dB)}$$

where $N$ is the filter length, and $B$ is the number of bits used for representing the filter coefficients. So for a filter with $N=50$ and $B=10$ you get $\epsilon\le -26\,\text{dB}$, which means that in the worst case the filter's stopband attenuation is only $26\,\text{dB}$. However, the authors mention that this bound is very conservative and that in practice the error is usually much smaller.

If the naive approach of filter design assuming infinite precision and subsequent coefficient quantization does not result in a useful filter, one must take coefficient quantization into account already during the design process. This can be done using integer programming techniques. The classic reference on this topic is [Design of Optimal Finite Wordlength FIR Digital Filters Using Integer Programming Techniques](http://laps.fri.uni-lj.si/~duke/HPpapers/assp80.pdf) by D.M. Kodek.

The following example illustrates the difference between the coefficient sensitivity of direct form implementations of FIR and IIR filters. I designed two lowpass filters: one 7th order elliptic IIR filter and one Parks-McClellan equiripple linear-phase FIR filter with $101$ taps, both filters satisfying approximately the same magnitude specifications. The plot below shows the magnitudes of the frequency responses (IIR in blue, FIR in green). The top two plots are the responses with unquantized coefficients, and the bottom plots are the responses with 14 bit fixed-point coefficients. Note the huge difference in coefficient sensitivity in the passband.

[image]

---

[1] T.W. Parks, C.S. Burrus, *Digital Filter Design*, p. 143

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was aware of the issues for IIR filters but am concerned with FIR implementation now.  Experimentally, I've seen the types of trade-offs that your bound above addresses.   Low pass filter coefficient magnitude tapers away from the origin of the filter and you soon run out of resolution for longer filters.  If you want to stick with low resolution coefficients, it seems like at some point you have to go with a cascaded structure (although with filters that can be much longer than SOSs).

Comment: I been primarily relying on matlab to help design quantized filters, but am a bit frustrated since 1) most of the time, you do not know what's going on under the hood, and 2) I can typically design better filters than matlab but hand tweaking and quantizing a filter myself.  I'd be interested in any good references you have on the integer programming techniques.

Comment: Matt, the same reason why cascading SOS for IIRs speaks to the **denominator** coefficient issue, can be said for cascading SOS for FIR regarding the *numerator* coefficients.  i s'pose you could say there were coefficient sensitivity issues either way.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: But the effect of coefficient quantization on the frequency response for a given filter order is of a totally different order of magnitude for the denominator polynomial of an IIR filter than for a FIR polynomial.

Comment: i fail to see the *"totally different order of magnitude"* between $$ -20 \log_{10}\left| e^{j\omega}-p_k \right| $$ and $$ +20 \log_{10}\left| e^{j\omega}-q_k \right| $$.  looks like they have about the same order of effect to me.  imagine you're $e^{j\omega}$ on the unit circle.  if you get close to either a pole or a zero, the frequency response, in dB will be adversely affected.  now they **don't** both affect stability the same.  and that's more than just a different order of magnitude.

Comment: @headdab: I've added a reference to integer programming FIR design to my answer.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: We don't quantize the pole and zero locations directly (which your example refers to), but the polynomial coefficients (talking about direct form). I've added an example to my answer. Note that I compare a 7th order IIR to a 100th order FIR filter because they have similar magnitude responses. Imagine what would happen if you quantized a 100th order direct form IIR filter ...

Comment: @MattL., you're being obtuse.  first, i never said "directly", but i don't even know what you mean by that.  it depends on the form, but assuming any of the "Direct Forms", we **most certainly** quantize the real part and the magnitude of **both** poles and zeros directly.  that's how we do it for Direct Forms.  for other forms we **still** quantize the poles and zeros in some manner.

Comment: **but the point is:** we normally quantize poles and zeros the same manner and your point regarding *"the effect of coefficient quantization on the frequency response for a given filter order is of a totally different order of magnitude for the denominator"* makes no sense (regarding frequency response).  makes a **big** difference regarding stability (denominator quantization is more salient).  but not regarding frequency response.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Not sure who's being obtuse here, but what I mean is that we quantize the *polynomial coefficients* if we talk about a direct implementation of the transfer function. Of course this implies pole and zero quantization, but only *indirectly* by quantizing the polynomial coefficients. The consequence of this can be seen in the example I added to my answer. What's your explanation of the difference in effect of coefficient quantization between FIR and IIR?

Comment: Matt, i know that there are filter structures where the mapping of coefficients to poles is different than the mapping of coefficients to zeros.  but, in the Direct Forms I and II and their transposes, the mapping of the coefficients (what you're emphasizing as *"polynomial coefficients"*) to poles is the same as it is to zeros: *you factor the polynomial to first-order factors.*  **in both the numerator and denominator.**  now, in **both** cases, you can factor to SOS and you will have better control over the pole and zero locations. for **both** the real part and the magnitude is quantized.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: The thing is I don't factor anything at all when I'm talking about the (pretty stupid) direct form structure. I just have two polynomials, one in the numerator and one in the denominator, and the quantization of the denominator polynomial coefficients has a more detrimental effect on the *frequency response* than the quantization of the numerator polynomial coefficients (see my example).

Comment: *"I don't factor anything at all when I'm talking about the direct form structure."* -- never said that you did. (the issue is what effect does the quantization on the coefficients of your unfactored Direct Form have on placements of the poles and zeros.) $$  $$ *"...the quantization of the denominator polynomial coefficients has a more detrimental effect on the frequency response than the quantization of the numerator polynomial coefficients"* -- no, that's mistaken, at least regarding dB gain (see my equations, err, *expressions* above, it's just as sensitive to zero placement as to poles).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I agree with your "dB argument", but I still wonder why in practice - at least for frequency selective filters - DF IIR filters perform much worse than DF FIR filters with quantized coefficients. It must have to do with the positions of zeros and poles for typical (frequency-selective) filters that a change in denominator polynomial coefficients usually has a much greater influence on the frequency response than an equivalent change in numerator coeffs. And, from my example above, FIR filters with quantized coeffs usually perform much better than equivalent IIR filters.

Comment: saying that "coefficient quantization has a more detrimental effect on frequency response for IIR filters (of some order) than for FIR filters (of a different order)" is not the same as saying that "quantization of denominator coefficients has a more detrimental effect on frequency response than does quantization of numerator coefficients".  that was the bone i was picking.  what i was trying to imply to the OP was that **maybe** factoring the FIR to cascade FIR SOS's *might* put a limit on how bad the coefficient quantization affects the zero placement. i dunno. i wouldn't bother to do it.

Comment: the way i have always felt about quantization of regular old FIR coefficients implemented with the regular ol' "transversal" implementation, is what quantization would do to an impulse response $h[n]$.  **if** the quantization is modeled as additive uniform p.d.f. random number of 1 LSB width, then the effect on frequency response would be like adding white noise.  all of the frequency-domain features would have little jaggies added to it.  but i wouldn't see it as specific errors of **tuning** the filter as i would see coefficient quantization affecting an IIR, specifically biquad sections.

Comment: BTW, at one time in my life, i had tried *noise-shaping* in the quantization of FIR coefficients.  as i recall, the noise-shaping was often opposite of the noise-shaping i did on the signal of a filter.  usually, in the latter, i would try to steer the error to the high-frequency portion of the spectrum (where it's harder to hear), but when quantizing $h[n]$, the high-frequency portion was often the stop-band and then i wanted to steer error *away* from the stop-band of $H(e^{j\omega})$, so i would steer it into the pass-band.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yes, there's also that [paper by Nielsen](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=32280&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel1%2F29%2F1399%2F00032280) about noise shaping for quantized FIR filters. I have never really looked into that though.

Comment: yeah, that paper rings a bell.  i wasn't IEEE and, unless i could get it free, i don't think i had it.  i might have it somewhere.  i probably re-invented some wheel.

Comment: @Matt L. I realize its been a while since you posted this answer, but when you said "14 bit fixed-point coefficients", does this mean 14 fractional bits + the sign bit + the integer bits, or 14 bits total? I mean for the entire IIR filter, not just coefficient quantization.

Comment: @user5108_Dan: It was 14 bits in total, but only for coefficient quantization. If you also do signal quantization then you're dealing with a non-linear system, which has no frequency response.